# React disable button while API is loading even when switching tabs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to disable the button when my API is loading. I have a disabled implemented, but whenever I switch the tab and then come back to the page, the button is enabled again. My button looks something like this:

```
      return (    
          <Button
            disabled={APIpost.isLoading}
            onClick={ () => APIpost.mutate(filter)}
          >
```

How can I implement a disabled function that disables the button while API is loading even when I switch tabs?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can promote the `APIpost` to the parent, and then pass `APIpost.isLoading` to this component which contains `Button`.